# Why do I get a "Dimension is too large" error?

Tags: pgfplots

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackge{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\resizebox{0.80\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[width=15cm,compat=1.5,height=9.5cm, legend columns=-1,
, axis line style=thick,
legend style={/tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=6.15cm}, at={(0,0)}, mark 
size=2.5pt, anchor=north east, at={(axis description cs:1.0,1.15)}, font=\small}, 
xlabel=\large periods, tick align=inside,
xtick={35,...,45},
ytick={0,10000,20000,...,1500000}, 
ylabel=\large Cases,
ymajorgrids=true,
grid style=dashed,
scaled x ticks=false,
        ]                                   
\addplot[very thick,mark size=2.5pt,color=cyan,mark=x]
       plot coordinates {
                (37,205945.16)
                (38,262273.00)
                (39,334005.49)
                (40,425355.53)
                (41,541688.17)
                (42,689835.69)
                (43,878498.89)
                (44,1118758.08)
                (45,1424723.84)
        };                                                              
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please format the rest of your code. However, I would guess that those numbers are too large e.g. `1424723.84`, and that TeX can't cope. I think you will need to scale them down for it to work i.e. input them after scaling them down appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

It's the `ytick` part that offends. Typically, `pgfplots` has no problems handling these numbers but when you use `<first>,<second>,...,<final>` syntax, `pgfplots` uses the TikZ `foreach` hence the TeX based `pgfmath` capabilities which are limited up to 16384. Then it trips up. You can either spell out the ticks or use `minor y tick num` as a quicker fix. You can also turn on the grid for those too if you wish.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackge{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[
  minor y tick num=5,
  ymajorgrids=true,
  grid style=dashed,
  scaled x ticks=false,
]

\addplot[very thick,mark size=2.5pt,color=cyan,mark=x]
    coordinates {
                (37,205945.16)
                (38,262273.00)
                (39,334005.49)
                (40,425355.53)
                (41,541688.17)
                (42,689835.69)
                (43,878498.89)
                (44,1118758.08)
                (45,1424723.84)
        };                                  
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much percusse, I really appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: @user28251 my pleasure.